# Unable to login on a newly installed Windows Server 2008 R2 because it came with a password

Tags: login, windows-server-2008-r2, password-management

I just installed a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise version. After rebooting, it asked me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> to login.

The problem is, I couldn't, because I had not set up a password, and the system is requiring one. How do I remove this default password?

Comment: Perhaps your Caps Lock or shift key is stuck?

Comment: that is considerable if you look at the question.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/50371/after-installing-windows-server-2008-what-is-the-default-password-for-the-local

Answer (score 1):

The default Administrator password is blank and you're required to change it on the first logon.

Answer (score 0):

I went to this link...

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c4a22367-a89a-47f8-8046-8ede12b2a21a/reset-password-on-windows-server-2008-r2?forum=winserversecurity

and found this….

Reset Windows server 2008r2 Password with Installation CD

Insert the installation disk to your locked computer, restart. When following interface appears. Click“Repair your computer”.

A dialog with several options pops up, click Command Prompt. 
When a Command Prompt black screen appears, type "copy c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe" and press Enter. Then type "copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe" afterwards press Enter key.

Restart your computer. On the login screen, tap Shift key five times and you'll see a command prompt screen in administrator mode. OK, type "net user UserName NewPassword" (replace the UserName and UserPassword with which you wanna) and press Enter key. The user password will be replaced with new one.

Close the window and then you can login that user with new password.

If you don't have the startup disk you may be out of luck.